# Integrate and serve React-Admin from existing Express application

Tags: reactjs, express, react-admin

In my project I need an administrator application. I have stumbled upon the admin-react. It seems it does exactly what I need it to do. I have checked their [tutorial](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html). Made some drafts, and got it running (following tutorial).

However I have an Express application that has routes and API's already working, and also I have React application served by the Express one. I would like to serve the Admin-React instead, in other words remove the existing React application and start customizing the React-Admin one as a static resource. Simply, my existing Express application should serve the React-Admin and expose the existing API's to it.

Looking at the tutorials, I found no information how to do it. It had yarn start and it starts running on port 3000.

I am missing something here very basic it seems.
Is there an example of that setup?

This is my Express.js that already serves React application (not React Admin) from public folder.

```
'use strict';
/* jshint camelcase:false */

require('dotenv').config();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === undefined) {
    throw new Error('No environment variable was set. For development use [export NODE_ENV=dev].');
}

let express = require('express');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
let path = require('path');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let expressValidator = require('express-validator');
let configuration = require('./app/Configuration');
let app = configuration.getApp();
let config = configuration.getParameters();
let errorHandler = require('./src/Error/Handler');
let session = require('client-sessions');

app.use(require('./src/Twig/ExtendWithCustomFunctions').extend());

app.use(session({
    cookieName: 'session',
    secret: 'xxxxxxx',
    duration: 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    activeDuration: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000 
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(errorHandler.bodyParser);
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));

configuration.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
configuration.initializeControllers(__dirname);

configuration.initializeErrorHandling();

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to serve a React Admin from an Express endpoint is to build it first.

If you followed the tutorial, you should have run a `create-react-app` application, so you can run the following command to bundle your app:

```
npm run build
# or
yarn build
```

Your bundle files will be available under the `static` folder.

Then, you can move these files to your express app, in a subfolder, where you'll be able to serve them with `express.static`.

More info about the create-react-app build & deployement: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment

There is even an example of how to serve the build: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#other-solutions